# How to resolve Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'schedulerService'?

Tags: java, spring-boot, kubernetes, openshift, spring-cloud-dataflow

I'm trying to install a [custom built SCDF2.5.1](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow-samples/tree/master/custom-dataflow-builds/dataflow-server-25x)(To add oracle Driver) into openshift (Followed the Kubectl installation doc for SCDF). I modified the deployment.yaml to pull this custom SCDF docker image of mine from git repo. Now when I start the container I get the below error

```
INFO  org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect.<init> - HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle12cDialect
INFO  org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.JtaPlatformInitiator.initiateService - HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
INFO  org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory - Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
INFO  org.springframework.cloud.dataflow.configuration.metadata.ApplicationConfigurationMetadataResolverAutoConfiguration.registryConfigurationMap - Final Registry Configurations: {registry-1.docker.io=RegistryConfiguration{registryHost='registry-1.docker.io', user='null', secret='****'', authorizationType=dockeroauth2, manifestMediaType='application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json', disableSslVerification='false', extra={registryAuthUri=https://auth.docker.io/token?service=registry.docker.io&scope=repository:{repository}:pull&offline_token=1&client_id=shell}}}
WARN  org.springframework.cloud.dataflow.server.config.features.SchedulerConfiguration.primaryTaskPlatform - TaskPlatform Kubernetes is selected as primary but has no TaskLaunchers configured
WARN  org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.cloud.dataflow.server.config.features.TaskConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'schedulerService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'schedulerService' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/dataflow/server/config/features/SchedulerConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.cloud.dataflow.server.service.SchedulerService]: Factory method 'schedulerService' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No valid primary TaskPlatform configured
INFO  org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.destroy - Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
INFO  com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.close - HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
INFO  com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.close - HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
INFO  org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.log - Stopping service [Tomcat]
ERROR
```

I saw a thread related to this post where the [fix](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow-server-kubernetes/issues/323) was provided to spring-cloud-dataflow-server-kubernetes and spring-cloud-dataflow-server-kubernetes-autoconfigure project. But I'm not sure whether thsose changes are available for the custom build 2.5.1 Release. Also I checked my deployment.yaml and the toggle "SPRING_CLOUD_DATAFLOW_FEATURES_SCHEDULES_ENABLED" was set to true.

In deployment.yaml I have removed database service & config, removed the scdf-server config as well, as I added the driver properties in application.properties while building the docker image itself. Below are the deployment.yaml and application.properties file which built into the scdf jar. FYI, removing the scdf-server config from deployment.yaml has no effect on the the failure. The above exception remains same. Also removed the skipper URI.

**deployment.yaml**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: customscdf-image
  labels:
    app: customscdf-image
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: customscdf-image
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: customscdf-image
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: customscdf-image
        image: docker-registry.default.svc:5000/scdfadmin/customscdf-image
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        livenessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /management/health
            port: 80
          initialDelaySeconds: 45
        readinessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /management/info
            port: 80
          initialDelaySeconds: 45
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: 1.0
            memory: 2048Mi
          requests:
            cpu: 0.5
            memory: 1024Mi
        env:
        - name: KUBERNETES_NAMESPACE
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: "metadata.namespace"
        - name: SERVER_PORT
          value: '80'
        - name: SPRING_CLOUD_CONFIG_ENABLED
          value: 'false'
        - name: SPRING_CLOUD_DATAFLOW_FEATURES_ANALYTICS_ENABLED
          value: 'true'
        - name: SPRING_CLOUD_DATAFLOW_FEATURES_SCHEDULES_ENABLED
          value: 'true'
        - name: SPRING_CLOUD_DATAFLOW_TASK_COMPOSED_TASK_RUNNER_URI
          value: 'docker://springcloud/spring-cloud-dataflow-composed-task-runner:2.6.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT'
        - name: SPRING_CLOUD_KUBERNETES_CONFIG_ENABLE_API
          value: 'false'
        - name: SPRING_CLOUD_KUBERNETES_SECRETS_ENABLE_API
          value: 'false'
        - name: SPRING_CLOUD_KUBERNETES_SECRETS_PATHS
          value: /etc/secrets
        - name: SPRING_CLOUD_DATAFLOW_SERVER_URI
          value: '${HOST_NAME}:9393'
          # Add Maven repo for metadata artifact resolution for all stream apps
        - name: SPRING_APPLICATION_JSON
          value: "{ \"maven\": { \"local-repository\": null, \"remote-repositories\": { \"repo1\": { \"url\": \"https://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot\"} } } }"
      serviceAccountName: scdf-sa
```

**application.properties**

```
spring.application.name=CUSTOMSCDF
spring.datasource.url=DATASOURCE_URL_FOR_ORACLE_DB
spring.datasource.username=user_name
spring.datasource.password=PASSWORD
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver

spring.flyway.enabled=false

spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.use-new-id-generator-mappings=true

logging.level.root=info
logging.file.max-size=5GB
logging.file.max-history=30 
logging.pattern.console=%d{dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger.%M - %msg%n
```

**Dockerfile** - Which will be built as customscdf-image used above

```
FROM maven:3.5.2-jdk-8-alpine AS MAVEN_BUILD

COPY pom.xml /build/
COPY src /build/src/

WORKDIR /build/
RUN mvn package

FROM openjdk:8-jre-alpine

WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=MAVEN_BUILD /build/target/custom-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar /app/

ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "custom-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
```

So what am I doing wrong or missing here? Please advice.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It could be that the Oracle driver that you're using is not compatible with the Hibernate version that we ship. If you can share the Spring Boot app that bundles SCDF's autoconfiguration, we could have a look.

Comment: Hi Anandan, I created a repo in Github. Below is the location. [custom-build:2.5.1+OracleDriver](https://github.com/Srkanna/SCDF_CustomBuild_2.5.1/tree/master/SCDFAdmin)

Comment: You should show full server startup log as that might tell more.

Comment: Janne, added the full log file in git repo.[CustomSCDF_OpenShift.log](https://github.com/Srkanna/SCDF_CustomBuild_2.5.1/blob/master/SCDFAdmin/CustomSCDF_OpenShift.log)

Comment: Hi I added my answer below.Why do you think the properties are not read if they're from server-config? I also saw some warnings in server-config file while trying to map it to deployments.
`WARNING:Config map scdf-server contains keys that are not valid environment variable names. Only config map keys with valid names will be added as environment variables.`
But I used the one from the SCDF-core projects. I couldn't exactly locate the issue for this one though. However if you think my answer below is valid, please let me know I can mark it as answer and close this thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This custom build doesn't read the server-config.yaml for some reason. Even if its shown in the server-deployment.yaml as one of the config-maps. So I moved the kubenetes task platform properties to application.properties of the CustomBuild SCDF Spring boot project. So the docker image I built from this project the kubernetes properties as well. After adding this the server-deployment.yaml able to get the k8 platform properties and SCDF started running successfully.

My application.properties currently looks like below.

```
spring.application.name=CustomSCDF
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@datasource_url
spring.datasource.username=username
spring.datasource.password=Password
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver

#properties moved from server-config.yaml
spring.cloud.dataflow.task.platform.kubernetes.accounts.default.image-pull-policy= always
spring.cloud.dataflow.task.platform.kubernetes.accounts.default.entry-point-style= exec
spring.cloud.dataflow.task.platform.kubernetes.accounts.default.limits.cpu=4
```

I think only the custom built application will face this issue. But this needs more clarity.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you are missing task platform configuration [server-config.yaml](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow/blob/43247faf52bd48c5e51ece6fdb72520e1c286b01/src/kubernetes/server/server-config.yaml#L35-L41) which is part of a k8s deployment files. As you're using your own `application.properties` file I have a feeling you didn't use that k8s config file.

Comment: Janne, I actually tried both options. But none seems to be working. Once I added server-config.yaml from deployment and started the container and next I removed and tried. Both yield the same results. I also attached the server-config.yaml and server-deployment.yaml in git repo.
[server-deployment.yaml](https://github.com/Srkanna/SCDF_CustomBuild_2.5.1/blob/master/SCDFAdmin/server-deployment.yaml)
[server-config.yaml](https://github.com/Srkanna/SCDF_CustomBuild_2.5.1/blob/master/SCDFAdmin/server-config.yaml)