# server-deployment.yml not reading values from server-config.yml in Spring Cloud Data flow server

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, spring-batch, openshift, spring-cloud-dataflow

I have deployed the Custom Built SCDF 2.52 in openshift environment which is up and running successfully. I followed the guide [2.5.0.RELEASE_Guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/2.5.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#getting-started). The Issue is the the properties given in server-config are not being considered by server-deployment.yaml file when I mount them. Though I could see the mappings for application.yaml is visible in deployment configuration, the properties are not read while the server is starting.

So when I build the custom scdf I have to add all the server properties including kubernetes memory limits, oracle datasource(External Datasource) properties in the scdf projects' application.properties file. Only then values of kube properties are being read platform being setup and External oracle datasource is getting connected. Below are the files that I'm using. I'm new to this SCDF and kubernetes. So please let me know if i'm missing anything anywhere.

Also why I added the kubernetes properties in application.properties of custom scdf project. [Reason here in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62031021/how-to-resolve-unsatisfied-dependency-expressed-through-field-schedulerservice/62046307#62046307)

**server-config.yaml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: scdf-server
  labels:
    app: scdf-server
data:
  application.yaml: |-
    spring:
      cloud:
        dataflow:
          task:
            platform:
              kubernetes:
                accounts:
                  default:
                    limits:
                      memory: 1024Mi
      datasource:
        url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@hostname:port/db
        username: root
        password: oracle-root-password
        driver-class-name: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
        testOnBorrow: true
        validationQuery: "SELECT 1"
```

**server-deployment.yaml**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: scdf-server
  labels:
    app: scdf-server
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: scdf-server
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: scdf-server
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: scdf-server
        image: docker-registry.default.svc:5000/batchadmin/scdf-server
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        volumeMounts:
          - name: config
            mountPath: /config
            readOnly: true
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        livenessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /management/health
            port: 80
          initialDelaySeconds: 45
        readinessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /management/info
            port: 80
          initialDelaySeconds: 45
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: 1.0
            memory: 2048Mi
          requests:
            cpu: 0.5
            memory: 1024Mi
        env:
        - name: KUBERNETES_NAMESPACE
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: "metadata.namespace"
        - name: SERVER_PORT
          value: '80'
        - name: SPRING_CLOUD_CONFIG_ENABLED
          value: 'false'
        - name: SPRING_CLOUD_DATAFLOW_FEATURES_ANALYTICS_ENABLED
          value: 'true'
        - name: SPRING_CLOUD_DATAFLOW_FEATURES_SCHEDULES_ENABLED
          value: 'true'
        - name: SPRING_CLOUD_DATAFLOW_TASK_COMPOSED_TASK_RUNNER_URI
          value: 'docker://springcloud/spring-cloud-dataflow-composed-task-runner:2.6.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT'
        - name: SPRING_CLOUD_KUBERNETES_CONFIG_ENABLE_API
          value: 'false'
        - name: SPRING_CLOUD_KUBERNETES_SECRETS_ENABLE_API
          value: 'false'
        - name: SPRING_CLOUD_KUBERNETES_SECRETS_PATHS
          value: /etc/secrets
        - name: SPRING_CLOUD_DATAFLOW_FEATURES_TASKS_ENABLED
          value : 'true'
        - name: SPRING_CLOUD_DATAFLOW_SERVER_URI
          value: 'http://${SCDF_SERVER_SERVICE_HOST}:${SCDF_SERVER_SERVICE_PORT}'
          # Add Maven repo for metadata artibatcht resolution for all stream apps
        - name: SPRING_APPLICATION_JSON
          value: "{ \"maven\": { \"local-repository\": null, \"remote-repositories\": { \"repo1\": { \"url\": \"https://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot\"} } } }"
      serviceAccountName: scdf-sa
      volumes:
        - name: config
          configMap:
            name: scdf-server
            items:
            - key: application.yaml
              path: application.yaml
```

**application.properties** - the Only thing that runs the SCDF right now.

```
spring.application.name=batchadmin
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@hostname:port/db
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=oracle_root_password
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver

spring.cloud.dataflow.task.platform.kubernetes.accounts.default.image-pull-policy= always
spring.cloud.dataflow.task.platform.kubernetes.accounts.default.entry-point-style= exec
spring.cloud.dataflow.task.platform.kubernetes.accounts.default.limits.cpu=2
spring.cloud.dataflow.task.platform.kubernetes.accounts.default.limits.memory=1024Mi

spring.flyway.enabled=false

spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.use-new-id-generator-mappings=true

logging.level.root=info
logging.file.max-size=5GB
logging.file.max-history=30 
logging.pattern.console=%d{dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger.%M - %msg%n
```

My main concern here apart from the above issue is db password. Since SCDF passes all the application.properties related to datasource and kubernetes as job_parameters including the db password, the password is being printed in the logs, visible in the running pod config and in batch_job_execution_params.

**Application.properties as Job params**
[image: Application.properties as Job params]

To summarize the issues here as questions,

1. server-config.yaml properties are not being used by server-deployment.yaml? What went wrong?
2. Since I pass server properties from application.prop file all the properties are visible in logs as well as Db. So is there a way I could hide them?
   Thanks in advance.

**server-role**

```
kind: Role
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: scdf-role
rules:
  - apiGroups: [""]
    resources: ["services", "pods", "replicationcontrollers", "persistentvolumeclaims"]
    verbs: ["get", "list", "watch", "create", "delete", "update"]
  - apiGroups: [""]
    resources: ["pods/log"]
    verbs: ["get", "list", "watch"]
  - apiGroups: ["apps"]
    resources: ["statefulsets", "deployments", "replicasets"]
    verbs: ["get", "list", "watch", "create", "delete", "update", "patch"]
  - apiGroups: ["extensions"]
    resources: ["deployments", "replicasets"]
    verbs: ["get", "list", "watch", "create", "delete", "update", "patch"]
  - apiGroups: ["batch"]
    resources: ["cronjobs", "jobs"]
    verbs: ["create", "delete", "get", "list", "watch", "update", "patch"]
```

Comment: Could you try to add `SPRING_CLOUD_KUBERNETES_CONFIG_NAME` as mentioned [here](https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-cloud-dataflow-server-kubernetes-docs/1.2.x/reference/html/configuration-general.html#configuration-general)? `The Spring Cloud Data Flow server for Kubernetes uses the Fabric8 spring-cloud-kubernetes module to process both ConfigMap and Secrets settings. You just need to enable the ConfigMap support by passing in an environment variable of SPRING_CLOUD_KUBERNETES_CONFIG_NAME and setting that to the name of the ConfigMap`

Comment: It didn't work. It's still not looking up the config-file properties. The server tries to load the default properties i.e., H2 db.could @ilayaperumal help here ?

Comment: Enabling the SPRING_CLOUD_KUBERNETES_CONFIG_ENABLE_API yield some different results. Now I get the `Forbidden!Configured service account doesn't have access. Service account may have been revoked. configmaps "scdf-server" is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:batchadmin:scdf-sa" cannot get configmaps in the namespace "batchadmin": no RBAC policy matched.`
I looked at scdf-sa account and its role scdf-server, it doesn't contain any resource named "configmaps". If it needs to be added explicitly under which apigroup it should fall? updated the scdf-role  file

Comment: Add it to your role as mentioned [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/#role-examples).

Comment: I added the configmap underdefault apigroup(1st one). Now the application reads the configmap from k8 and runs. But the still the password is visible as job parameter.

Comment: Then as mentioned [here](https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-cloud-dataflow-server-kubernetes-docs/1.2.x/reference/html/configuration-general.html#configuration-general) maybe instead of configmap use [secret](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/#creating-a-secret-using-kubectl) to store  hash password here?

Comment: Nope. It's not working either. The password still gets printed.